# CakePHP - Handle not- authorized but logged in user

Tags: php, cakephp

im working on a CakePHP site however im having some issues with the Authorization part of it. If i have a Logged In user who tries to access a resource that they are not allowed it throws a forbidden exception. I need this to redirect to a friendly page stating that they are not allowed and why. Can i do this without setting a global error 403 page.

Comment: Why tagged [tag:laravel] ?

Comment: Please always mention the exact CakePHP version that you are using (last line in `lib/Cake/VERSION.txt` or `vendor/cakephp/cakephp/VERSION.txt`), and in this case also whether you are using the auth component, or the authorization plugin - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**[Checking Authorization](https://book.cakephp.org/authorization/2/en/component.html#checking-authorization)** says:

> The authorize() method will raise an
> Authorization\Exception\ForbiddenException when permission is denied.
> **If you want to check authorization and get a boolean result** you can
> use the can() method:

```
if ($this->Authorization->can($article, 'update')) {
    // Do something to the article.
} else {
    $this->Flash->error('Your error message here');
    // or set view vars:
    // $not_authorized = [
    //    'title' => '...',
    //    'reson' => ...,
    //    'solution' => ....
    // ];
    // $this->set('not_authorized', $not_authorized);
    $this->render('not_authorized');

}
```